# Clip number within range in Scala

Tags: scala

Give an integer `x`, I'd like to return `x` if it's within the boundaries of some range.  If not, return the value of the boundary it violates.

```
def keepWithinRange(x:Int, min:Int, max:Int) : Int = {
  if (x < min) return min;
  if (x > max) return max;
  return x;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd write this:

```
def keepWithinRange(x: Int, min: Int, max: Int) = math.max(min, math.min(max, x))
```

Or this:

```
def keepWithinRange(x: Int, min: Int, max: Int) =
  if (x < min) min else if (x > max) max else x
```

Either is more idiomatic than using `return` for control flow in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

You can use max and min methods from RichInt:

```
def keepWithinRange(x:Int, minVal:Int, maxVal:Int) = x max minVal min maxVal
```

Comment: This is one case where I don't think the infix operator notation helps readability (and using `RichInt` methods costs the creation of a couple of wrapper objects).

Comment: @Travis `a max b` has exactly the same run time as `math.max(a,b)`, on my machine at least. Not sure if compiler or runtime optimization.